# How to enable on click listener from activity when fragment has been fully loaded?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am declaring my fragments like so in my activity:

```
public void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewP) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new ProjectPro1(), "proj1");
        adapter.addFragment(projectPro2 = new ProjectPro2(), "proj2");
        viewP.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Now in my activity at the very end of everything being done I call a setOnClickListener on a button which works fine if the fragments fully load - since when clicked the button tells a fragment not in view to update part of its view. However, if I click on the button right away then it will crash the app since the fragment is not fully loaded yet and gives a null error. How can I have the button enabled once the fragment is fully loaded or setTheOnClicklistener when a fragment is fully loaded?

**EDIT:**

To make things clearer - I have a follow button that displays on both fragments. One on fragment it shows just pictures on the other fragment it shows the person's details. If a user clicks the follow button on either fragment the count on the details fragment has to update (followers count + 1).

UPDATE:

This is the attempt for your answer adelphus - This is my fragment class:

```
    private boolean profileDetailsCreated = false;
    private boolean trackChanged = false;
    private int trackValue = 0;
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.project_profile_details, container, false);

   profileDetailsCreated = true;

        if(trackChanged) {
            Log.d(Constants.DEBUG, "THE TRACK CHANGED HAS OCCURED BEFORE PROFILE DETAILS CREATED");
            setTrackCount(trackValue);
        }

        return rootView;
}


 public void setTrackCount(int value) {
        Log.d(Constants.DEBUG, "THE value for set track count is " + value);
        if(profileDetailsCreated) {
            Log.d(Constants.DEBUG, "THE PROFILE DETAIL IS CREATED CHANGE SHOULD HAPPEN");
            dbProject.setTrackedCount(trackC + value);
            db.projectUpdateTrack(dbProject);
            trackC = dbProject.getTrackedCount();

            showTrackBackgroundText();
        } else {
            Log.d(Constants.DEBUG, "THE PROFILE DETAIL IS NOT CREATED STORE THE DATA " + value);
            trackValue = value;
            trackChanged = true;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can't you just set the button's onClickListener inside `onCreateView` of the *fragment*, not the activity?

Comment: I am using the button on both fragments

Comment: In that case, you should probably not be attempting to update any views on each fragment until `onCreateView()` has been called on them. Just save the info needed to perform the update in the fragment instance itself and make the update happen when onCreateView is called.

Comment: That is the problem. Just to paint the picture clearer, I have two fragments - the fragment that is first in display is not affected by the button but displays it, the second fragment is affected. Now this button can be clicked any time, way after onCreateView is called or before, so if I save it, then I can have onCreateView change accordingly and grab the saved info but after it is created already how would it be notified... see the comment I wrote on the other answer - that seems to be the only solution that I can think of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon your comments, I'll try and make my explanation a bit clearer. It's difficult to visualise what problem you're facing since you don't describe what the update does.

Here is my suggestion (in psuedo-code):

```
class MainActivity extends Activity {
   public void onCreate(..) {
        ...
        // assuming the button is part of the activity view
        btn.setOnClickListener((View) => {
              Info info = getInfoNeededForUpdate();
              fragment1.update(info);
              fragment2.update(info);
        });
   }
}

// Frag2 is the same logic as Frag1
class Frag1 extends Fragment {
    boolean mCreated;
    Info mPendingInfo;

    public void onCreateView(...) {
         // inflate view, blah
         ...
         // mark us as created
         mCreated = true

         // apply any pending updates         
         if (mPendingInfo != null)
            this.update(info);
    }

    public void update(Info info) {
        // first check if we've been created
        if (this.mCreated) {
            // yep - go ahead and apply the updates to the views
            ...
        } else {
            // nope - save it for later (update will be applied in onCreateView)
            this.mPendingInfo = info;
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully you can see from this that it doesn't matter when the update is applied to the fragment - the view will either get updated immediately (if the fragment's `onCreateView()` has already been called) or it will wait until `onCreateView()` is called before applying the update.

Comment: I am implementing this, first off my fragment is in a separate class file, second, I store it correctly and everything it just never gets called in the onCreateView with the if else statement. Also, now waiting a while before hitting the follow button still shows as if the view was never created... I will add the changes for you to see.

Comment: @Lion789 your update looks correct. `onCreateView()` is not normally called until the view is actually shown, so it should appear as if the view was never created if you've never displayed it. When you say *"it just never gets called in the onCreateView with the if else statement"*, do you mean `onCreateView()` never gets called on the fragment or that method is called but the value of `trackChanged` is false?

Comment: The boolean is always false, no matter how many times I click the button, which makes no sense because I am setting it true. I tried removing the initialization of both booleans to nothing, but profileDetailsCreated in my Log is always showing up as false.

Comment: Not sure I can help you past this point without debugging the code myself. If you're seeing the correct debug msgs in `setTrackCount()`, it looks like multiple instances of the fragment are being constructed, but without the full code, I'm not sure what to suggest. Perhaps try setting breakpoints in the fragment constructor, `setTrackCount()` and `onCreateView()` to see what gets called.

Comment: It seems that the profileDetailsCreated is true in onCreateView - but then loses its value on setTrackCount when the method is called from the activity...

Comment: @Lion789 That definitely sounds like two different fragment instances. You could just initialise an int field to a random value and check the value is the same between the two method calls - if it's changed, you know you're looking at two different fragment instances.

Comment: Good call, did not even notice that I was creating a second instance, Thanks for that

Answer (score 1):

In this case you should do the setting of the `OnClickListener` in the `onActivityCreated` lifecycle method:

```
private Button yourButton;
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    View rooView = getView();
    yourButton  = (Button) rooView.findViewById(R.id.your_button);
    //then you can set the 
    yourButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {           
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //do stuff here!    
            }
        }); 
}
```

Comment: This would be fine if I did not have both fragments using the button, therefore I have the button in the activity view, and both fragments take the space inbetween the button and the action bar - therefore I have to have the onclick set in the activity not in the fragment... the only solution I can think of is by setting the onclicklistener when the fragment is loaded and calling an interface to the activity to set the onClick

Comment: So you say both the fragments are using a single button? So in this case the button is not in one of the Fragment's layout files but in the activity? What do these fragments use the button for?

Comment: sorry about that look at the edit, gave the real example to make it clearer